# Is it possible to force a <script type="module"> to be sync

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vite

When you include a `<script type="module">` in an html page, its content is fetched and executed in parallel to the parsing of the page. Reference: https://v8.dev/features/modules#defer
[image: Flow]
I am trying to integrate [ViteJS](https://vitejs.dev/) in a legacy application and the fact that the code is loading in parallel is causing problems with older code expecting scripts earlier in the page to have already run.

Setting async to the script tag `<script type="module" async>` helps a bit for race conditions with existing legacy code, but race conditions can definitely still happen.

**Is it possible to force a script tag of type module to run synchronously?**

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know `defer` makes scripts wait for html to load before running.

Comment: In this case I have to use script type="module" to take advantage of ViteJS in development.  The problem is that when the script of of type=module, then the page continues to parse and potentially execute other script tags in the help that would normally depend in the code in the script type=module...  But since it runs in parallel, the required code might not have run.

Comment: Did you try to make all scripts `defer`?

Comment: This is a legacy app, some scripts are getting injected in the page after ajax calls appending html containing other scripts in the page etc.  For example an ajax call append html to the page containing a script type=module AND a normal script.  The normal script expects code from the script type=module to have already run.
Code compile using ViteJS needs to run in a script type=module in dev to benefit from ViteJS features.

Comment: As Xion said, You can try making all scripts `defer` (including modules). The `defer` scripts wait for the parser and then load the scripts in the order that they encountered. Since you mentioned that some of your scripts require the module, You can place them right after the required module in order to execute after the module.